# Async object does not get returned from getInitialProps despite success elsewhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

I'm just starting to figure out React by putting together a bit of code from different parts, and from an online course.

I'm using React, Next and Axios to get an API from a cryptocurrency server.

The main issue I'm facing is:

- I am able to console.log(coinObjects) under getInitialProps, and it displays the object correctly
- Despite this, coinObjects **does not** get rendered in {this.props.coinObjects}
- As a possible clue, linksArr **does** get rendered in {this.props.linksArr}

The code I have is as follows:

```
    class MainIndex extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps(props) {
        // setup - empty array and list of coins
        const coinList = ["NEO", "ETH", "BTC"];
        const numCoins = coinList.length;
        const coinObjects = [];
        const linksArr = [];
        const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";

        // API GET
        const baseUrl = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?";
        for (let coinName of coinList) {
        linksArr.push(
            baseUrl.concat("fsym=", coinName, "&tsym=", "USD", "&limit=", "3")
        );
        }

        const getObj = async linksArr => {
        try {
            let res = await axios.all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l)));
            for (let i = 0; i < linksArr.length; i++) {
            coinObjects[coinList[i]] = res[i].data.Data;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        };
        await getObj(linksArr);
        console.log(coinObjects);

        // Return updated arrays
        if (isServer) {
        return { coinObjects, numCoins, linksArr };
        } else {
        return {};
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <Layout>
        <h2>
          CoinObject has {this.props.coinObjects.length} coins
          // Returns 0
          <br />
          LinksArr has {this.props.linksArr.length} links
          // Returns 3
        </h2>
        </Layout>
        );
    }
    }
```

Could anyone please help me? I've exhausted all the Google searches, Stackoverflow posts and coding friends that I can find (just 1). I can't figure out what's wrong, and I hope that this isn't a silly question because I've been tweaking and changing things extensively, but have yet to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `coinObject` is set to an array:

```
const coinObjects = [];
```

But later is treated as an Object:

```
coinObjects[coinList[i]] = res[i].data.Data;
```

That means that you would want to add to the array like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < linksArr.length; i++) {
  let data = res[i].data.Data;
  let name = coinList[i];

  coinObjects.push({ name: name, data: data });
}
```

Comment: This is incredible, thanks so much for your help!!! I thought I could treat the Array like an Object because console.log printed the right Object... Was so confused when I assumed that wasn't the problem. Thanks a bunch!!